# How get Single Url From an Array of urls?

Tags: arrays, swift, url

This is My Code:

```
  urll = NSURL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/?slider=uij6sdnb")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urll) {(NSData, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            let records = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(NSData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
            for record in records {
                //                    let urlid = Int(record["slide_id"] as! String)
                let urimage = record["slide_url"] as! String
                self.urls = [urimage]
                print(self.urls.count)
                                }
        }

        catch {
            print("Json Error")

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

When I Print :

```
              print(urimage)
```

it gaves me 4 url like this:

http://sdkladlkasjd1.jpg

http://sdkladlkasjd2.jpg

http://sdkladlkasjd3.jpg

http://sdkladlkasjd4.jpg

When I print:

```
              print(urimage[1])
```

It gaves me :
 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion

When i put it in another value :

```
var urls = [String]()
self.urls = [urimage]
```

and I print:

```
                print(self.urls.count)
```

it gaves me

1

1

1

1

How on earch I can access one of this urls !?

I want to Show them on imageview but I can !

Comment: You get multiple URLs because of your loop over `records`. Each record has a `slide_url` which you are saving in `urimage` and print it out. It is unclear which one you want, but if the first one is okay, why not just replace your loop with something like `let urimagae = records[0]["slide_url"] as! String`?

Comment: Thank you ! I want All of them seperatly ! How can I get Them All !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Julian Kniephoff rightly mentioned, you are printing each URL in the for loop, thus you cannot access one particular one. However, there is also another issue, in that you are replacing the `urls` array with the latest url each time.

To solve this, simply replace the line `self.urls = [urimage]` with `self.urls.append(urimage)`.

You can then access a particular image *outside* the `for` loop by doing something like `self.urls[1]`.

This is also why `print`ing the count of the array returns 1, since each time around you are setting the array to just the one latest element in the loop.

In the end, your code may look something like this

```
url = NSURL(string: "http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/?slider=uij6sdnb")
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
    do {
        let records = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
        for record in records {
            //let urlid = Int(record["slide_id"] as! String)
            let urimage = record["slide_url"] as! String
            self.urls.append(urimage)
        }
        print(self.urls[1]) //Prints http://sdkladlkasjd2.jpg
    }
    catch {
        print("Json Error")
    }
    //print(self.urls[1])
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: When I print this :                    print(self.urls[1])
 ... its game me fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: @Alfi can you do `print(self.urls)` and tell me what it says?

Comment: and when i print :                     print(self.urls) its game me 16 multiplied of those 4 url !

Comment: @Alfi are you sure that you're printing *outside* of the for loop?

Comment: @Alfi try copying my code exactly, and tell me whether it gives you an error

Comment: I have an error on data! when I use your code but I'm working on it to fix it

Comment: @Alfi replace `data!` with what you had before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118125/discussion-between-kabiroberai-and-alfi).